# How to always get latest Firebase Auth Token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, token

Currently I am using this code to get the latest auth token for firebase, which I use in a header with Apollo or URQL to query something else to be validated...

```js
async getToken(): Promise<any> {
  return await new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
    this.afa.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken(true).then((token: string) => {
          resolve(token);
        }, (e: any) => reject(e));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I am use `getIdToken(true)` to always make sure I get a valid token since the token expires after one hour and the custom claims could be updated at some point.

However, my code gets a new token every time, when really I only need to get a new token when the old one is expired, or there is new information in the token's custom claim.

Should I be using some for of `onIdTokenChanged()` ?  Does firebase store all this automatically in the firebase localstoreage db (IndexedDB), or should I be using some form of localstorage and calculating the expiry time ?

Basically, what is the best way to minimize the number of refreshes to the token to speed up my app instead of getting a new token every time?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a custom solution with the REST API, the firebase client modules will automatically refresh the auth token with the refresh token when the old one expires.

As for updating the custom claims, you will have to communicate with the client app through some means such as a server response if you invoke a cloud function or a realtime database listener that the user is subscribed to if you are updating it based on 'external' conditions.